# react set state not working on keyboard dismiss?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple function like this i just copied it from react documentation  , the alert works perfectly but my function `changeDescription` do nothing even if i put a simple setstate  ?? what did i do wrong ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);



    this.changeDescription = this.changeDescription.bind(this);
    this.sendDescription = this.sendDescription.bind(this);
    this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this);

  }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
          'keyboardDidShow',
          this._keyboardDidShow,
        );
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
          'keyboardDidHide',
          this._keyboardDidHide,
        );
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      }

      _keyboardDidHide() {

        const { member } = this.props;

        alert(member.description)
        this.changeDescription('ok')
      }


      changeDescription = (val) => {

        // console.log(val)

        this.setState({ description: val })

      }



 <Textarea

                defaultValue={member.description}
                onChangeText={v => this.changeDescription(v)}



              />
```

Comment: Where are you getting the Textarea component?

Comment: nativebase it's basically .a TextInput

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using the description state ?  I see the setting of the state but no usage.

Comment: Its not clear what you expect to happen when you execute: this.setState({ description: val }

Comment: its on the textarea ?

Comment: @Chev i just change the state of my textinput ?

Comment: @manyouuwx you mean the member.description ? member is a prop and description is a state

Comment: @manyouuwx but you only set a default value at the start which is the state.member.description, I don't see a value bound to state.description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you just need to set the value of your Textarea

```
<Textarea
  defaultValue={member.description}
  onChangeText={v => this.changeDescription(v)}
  value={this.state.description} />
```

Comment: thanks do you know the right syntax for :  onChangeText={v => this.changeDescription(v)}
                        {this.state.description ? value = {this.state.description} : null}

Comment: if i want to render value depending if description if empty

Comment: The defaultValue should handle that for you. Does it not?

Comment: yeah but how can i bring back to the default value